# How exactly does the front camera zoom in iPhone 14 Pro (Max) works?

Tags: ios, camera, zoom

iPhone 14 Pro has 3 front cameras with 4 default zoom numbers. When you choose 0.5x it uses ultrawide camera. However, 1x and 2x seems to use main (wide) camera up to 3x. At 3x the telephoto camera is used instead. I tested this by covering telephoto camera. Until 3x zoom nothing changes if you cover it. At 3x and more, the picture is obscured. Does it imply that from 1x to 3x the zoom is only digital, exactly at 3x it is optical and after that it is digital again? Similar thing for zoom between 0.5x and 1x.

This question is different from suggested question: [Optical Zoom on iPhone Xs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461766/optical-zoom-on-iphone-xs) because it is regarding different phone with different number of cameras which might work differently.

Comment: "Different phone with different numbers of cameras" doesn't change how physics or this technology works.

Comment: It is ridiculous to claim that same technology is used on every phone or camera.

Answer (score 0):

Your summation is accurate from my understanding.

- 0.5x-0.9x uses the ultra wide
- 1x-2.9x uses the main camera
- 3x and above uses the telephoto lens

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes. But how does the zoom work then? The wider lens loose quality but smaller lens are not wide enough. Which should mean that only part of the picture can be zoomed optically.